# How to create custom helper file in laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, helper, autoload

When I create an autoload helper file with composer following error ocures:

> Fatal error: composerRequireebefe31fc60fbe2897fba8c156ec310c(): Failed
>   opening required
>   'D:\xampp\htdocs\common_module\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/helpers.php'
>   (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\common_module\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on
>   line 66

Comment: Can you post your `composer.json` file? Where is your `helpers.php` file located?

Answer (score 7):

Following are steps to create a Custom Helper In Laravel 5.5

> Step : 1 Create app/helpers.php file

First, create one helper class file in app/helpers.php path and in this file we are write our any custom helper logic into the function.

> Step : 2 Add app/helpers.php file in composer.json file

Now, we are add our app/helpers.php file in composer.json file for a autoload section.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [

         ...

     ],

    "psr-4": {

         "App\\": "app/"

    },

    "files": [

         "app/helpers.php" //Add This Line

    ]
},
```

After done this then once we are run following command.

> composer dump-autoload

for more visit following link

Visit [How To Create Custom Helper In Laravel 5.5](https://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-create-custom-helper-in-laravel-55)

I hope this will help you...

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

In older version of Laravel I do the following:

1. app folder create a Helpers folder
2. Create a class YourHelper class file
3. in that class file set namespace to App\Helpers
4. Name the class file
5. in config/app.php in aliases create an alias (so you can call the helper in your view also) **'YourHelper'=>'App\Helpers\YourHelper::class'**

Comment: perfect! Exactly what I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Laravel or PHP, let’s walk through how you might go about creating your own helper functions that automatically get loaded by Laravel.

**Creating a Helpers file in a Laravel App**

you can organize the location of your helper file(s) however you want, however, here are a few suggested locations:

- app/helpers.php
- app/Http/helpers.php

I prefer to keep mine in app/helpers.php in the root of the application namespace.

**Autoloading**

PHP functions cannot be autoloaded. However, we have a much better solution through Composer than using require or require_once.

So composer has a files key (which is an array of file paths) that you can define inside of autoload:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ],
         "classmap": [
         "database/seeds",
         "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
         "App\\": "app/"
     }
},
```

Once you add a new path to the files array, you need to dump the autoloader:

```
 composer dump-autoload
```

(Use this command after changing composer.json.)

Now on every request the helpers.php file will be loaded automatically because Laravel requires Composer’s autoloader in public/index.php:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

**Defining Functions**

Defining functions in your helpers class is the easy part, although, there are a few caveats. All of the Laravel helper files are wrapped in a check to avoid function definition collisions:

```
if (! function_exists('env')) {
    function env($key, $default = null) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I prefer to use function_exists checks in my application helpers, but if you are defining helpers within the context of your application, you could forgo the function_exists check.